# How do I streamline/automate data-entry?

Tags: database, web

I'm looking to create a website around a tool that plugs info from different sites into a form on mine.  I'd like to eliminate/streamline data-entry.  Anyone know a good way to accomplish this?

Comment: It will highly depend on your form and website from which data is being imported. You can write scrapper in php or python.

Comment: I'm looking to grab data from a couple of different websites containing specific bits of information in text form, like from a resume, and then plug it in to a fillable form, like text boxes, that can then be used to calculate a result based on a pre-determined algorithm.  Like plugging things in to an excel spreadsheet, and having a number automatically displayed on my site without all of the workings being displayed for the user.

Answer (score 0):

There are plenty of web scraper scripts available on github that can do data capture from web.

You will still need programming skills to change and plug those scripts as per your requirement. [Here](https://github.com/grangier/python-goose) is one such parser but you must know basic [DOM](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_htmldom.asp) and programming to access information of your need from a website.

Apart from this you can also use excel sheet to access web data and then you can fill your form with that data.

You should try to learn **web scraping using python**. Threre are plenty of web based tutorials for it. Youtube may also be helpful.